# listview in TornadoFX displaying duplicated items when using cache-form

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I'm loading JSON data from internet, capturing data about items, like name, author and imageurl. Then I want to load them one under the other so I put them into the listview. I only add them once as a custom class, that only holds those variables.

I'm having a problem with those values duplicating and not appearing as they should. For example, it would load first 5 items(out of 20) and it would repeat them over the remaining 15. I don't understand why that's happening, also tried with looping over listview's `items` array and printing them out and they are all different, also tried doing refresh() on them, but it doesn't seem to change anything at all.

I'm adding a code that I use to create the listview and the piece that I'm using to fill it in.

```
val lv = listview<Item>{
    anchorpaneConstraints {
        topAnchor = 0.0
        bottomAnchor = 0.0
        leftAnchor = 0.0
        rightAnchor = 0.0
    }
    cellFormat {
        graphic = cache {
            form {
                fieldset {
                    hbox {
                        spacing = 10.0
                        println(it.name)
                        println(it.author)
                        println(it.imgurl)
                        println(it.desc)
                        imageview {
                            image = Image(it.imgurl)
                            prefWidth(256.0)
                            prefHeight(256.0)

                        }
                        vbox {
                            field("Name") {
                                label(it.name)
                            }
                            field("Author") {
                                label(it.author)
                            }
                            field("Description") {
                                label {
                                    text = it.desc
                                    wrapWidth = 150
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

val tmpItems = items.clone() as ArrayList<JsonObject>()
val arr = ArrayList<Item>()
for (m in tmpItems) {
    arr.add(
    Item(
        m["name"].toString(),
    m["author"].toString(),
    m["desc"].toString(),
    m["imgUrl"].toString()
    )
)
}
lv.items.addAll(arr)
```

I expected the output to be 20 unique items, as that's what's in the `lv.items`, but the shown result is 5 unique items repeated over 20 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `cache` you need to specify a unique id for each item, so the framework knows how to retrieve the cached ui elements for the currently displayed item in a given table cell. This is explained in detail in the javadoc for the `cache` function.

If you have an id field in your item, you can use that for example:

`cache(rowItem.id) { }`

You could even use the value for the cell, if that's unique:

`cache(it) { }`

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer, so if I have a class, which attribute "name" is unique, I can use `cache(it.name) {}` or did I misunderstand it?

Comment: Using the second example made it work for me. Thanks!